# When Moshiach comes how will people know about God?

Tags: theology, messiah, navi-prophets, zecharia-book-of

When mosiach comes it says everybody in the whole world will believe in Hashem ([Zecharya 8](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2308.htm):23):

> כֹּה אָמַר ה' צְבָאוֹת בַּיָּמִים הָהֵמָּה אֲשֶׁר יַחֲזִיקוּ עֲשָׂרָה אֲנָשִׁים מִכֹּל לְשֹׁנוֹת הַגּוֹיִם וְהֶחֱזִיקוּ בִּכְנַף אִישׁ יְהוּדִי לֵאמֹר נֵלְכָה עִמָּכֶם כִּי שָׁמַעְנוּ אֱלֹהִים עִמָּכֶם
>
> Thus saith the LORD of hosts: In those days it shall come to pass, that ten men shall take hold, out of all the languages of the nations, shall even take hold of the skirt of him that is a Jew, saying: We will go with you, for we have heard that God is with you.'

But what about the uncontacted tribes, for examples in the Amazon rainforest, Papua New Guinea? How will they find out about Hashem, since they aren't known to the rest of mankind -- they didn't have any prior contact with Jews, so they couldn't have found out through them, as the above verse claims.

Comment: If they aren't known, how do you know they do not already believe in Hashem?

Comment: Why does the fact that they are uncontacted preclude them from believing in Hashem?

Comment: @Daniel The _pasuk_ explicitly precords contact with Jews.

Comment: There are three close votes for unclear; I don't see what is unclear about the current iteration of this question. The first revision, maybe; but the question is pretty clear now.

Comment: open miracles...

Comment: @Shokhet: #1- Perhaps the close votes came b4 the revision. #2- Perhaps there are those that still find this question unclear.

Comment: @GershonGold I figured the votes came by before the revision. I just came by this question in the review queue, and wanted others in the review queue to consider my opinion before voting, should they choose to vote.

Comment: Generally, the biblical concept of "all" does NOT literally mean ALL. There is consistent reference to the "70 languages/nations of the world." There are FAR more than 70 languages, and these do NOT split along nation-state lines at ALL (with perhaps the sole exception of Israel). So... maybe these reclusive tribes WON'T be involved?

Comment: Somewhat anti-anticlimactically, verses often speak in generalities. Thus it is possible to suggest that the verse speaks of מִכֹּל לְשֹׁנוֹת הַגּוֹיִם, and it just means the vast majority of them. (See hassags of Ramban to Shoresh Rshon where he mentions this prnciple, and Hamaspik L'ovdey Hashem Shaar Habitachon of R. Avraham Ben HaRambam mention it as well.)

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky jinx! on a serious note, where does the Bible say that there are 70 languages?

Comment: Three places: Migdal Bavel (gen. 11) delineates nations and linguistic lines, the start of Devarim  (1:5) and Ki Tavo (27:2) re: writing the Torah (or some portion thereof) on stones. Chazal (Sotah 32a, Medrash tanchuma 2) say that the reference there to "Ba'er heytev" is the 70 languages of the world from Bavel.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremiah 29:14 might add some insight into how the process might work:
 יד. וְנִמְצֵאתִי לָכֶם נְאֻם יְהֹוָה וְשַׁבְתִּי אֶת שְׁבוּתְכֶם וְקִבַּצְתִּי אֶתְכֶם מִכָּל הַגּוֹיִם וּמִכָּל הַמְּקוֹמוֹת אֲשֶׁר הִדַּחְתִּי אֶתְכֶם שָׁם נְאֻם יְהֹוָה וַהֲשִׁבֹתִי אֶתְכֶם אֶל הַמָּקוֹם אֲשֶׁר הִגְלֵיתִי אֶתְכֶם מִשָּׁם:

"And I will be found by you, says the L-rd, and I will return your captivity and gather you from all the nations and from all the places where I have driven you, says the L-rd, and I will return you to the place whence I exiled you."

This verse implies that the uncontacted tribes will find G-d on their own, but G-d Himself will play an active role in returning them to Israel.

Comment: That's referring to the Jews who were exiled from Jerusalem by N'vuchadnetzar. I think the OP was referring to non-Jewish aboriginal peoples.

Comment: I am not certain whether this prophecy refers to the gathering of the Bablylonian exile or the second (current) exile.  But according to some, this verse refers to the second (final) redemption.

Comment: Even if you understand this as a duel reference including the final redemption, it's talking about the exiles from Jerusalem (i.e. the Jews), unlike *Z'charya* 8:23 referenced in the OP.

Comment: God will reveal Himself in the war of gog u'magog as we read in the haftorah of sukkot

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam says about the times of Moshiach that the whole world will be filled with knowledge of Hashem as the waters cover the sea. The Rambam also says that the only true existence is Hashem. In golus, nature masks Hashem to make it look like there is existence other than Hashem but when Moshiach comes the mask will be lifted and it will be clear to everyone's eyes that the only existence is in fact Hashem.

Therefore, no matter where one finds himself he will see Hashem.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodea - the exact source of the Rambam would enhance the quality of this answer.